# Sharing a C++ pointer with LLVM JIT'd code

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I want to have most of my program be an ordinarily compiled C++ program.  Said program uses a chunk of contiguous memory for a stack.  The top of the stack is maintained by an ordinary pointer.

I want to share that pointer with code generated via LLVM JIT.  For example, given:

```
llvm::InitializeNativeTarget();

llvm::LLVMContext ctx;
std::unique_ptr<llvm::Module> uptr_module = llvm::make_unique<llvm::Module>( "lt", ctx );
llvm::Module *const module = uptr_module.get();

int *const stack = new int[100];
int *top = stack;                 // I want this pointer to be shared with JIT'd code

llvm::Function *const func = llvm::cast<llvm::Function>(
    module->getOrInsertFunction( "func", llvm::Type::getVoidTy( ctx ), (llvm::Type*)0 )
);
llvm::BasicBlock *const block = llvm::BasicBlock::Create( ctx, "entry", func );

pointerInc( &top, block );        // Increment the pointer in JIT'd code

llvm::ReturnInst::Create( ctx, block );
llvm::verifyFunction( *func, &llvm::outs() );
llvm::verifyModule( *module, &llvm::outs() );
module->dump();

llvm::EngineBuilder eb( std::move( uptr_module ) );
llvm::ExecutionEngine *const exec = eb.create();
assert( exec );

void *const func_ptr = exec->getPointerToFunction( func );
assert( func_ptr );
typedef void (*PFv_v)();
(*(PFv_v)func_ptr)();             // Call JIT'd function
```

where `pointerInc()` will insert JIT'd code into the current `BasicBlock` to increment `top`.  The `pointerInc()` code is:

```
// Convert a raw C++ pointer into an LLVM Constant*.
template<typename T>
inline llvm::Value* ptrToValue( T **pptr, llvm::LLVMContext &ctx ) {
    return return llvm::ConstantInt::get( llvm::Type::getInt64Ty( ctx ), (uint64_t)pptr );
}

void pointerInc( llvm::Constant *pptrAsInt64, llvm::ConstantInt *sizeof_T,
                 llvm::BasicBlock *block ) {
    llvm::LLVMContext &ctx = block->getContext();

    llvm::Constant *const intToPtr8 = llvm::ConstantExpr::getIntToPtr(
        pptrAsInt64, llvm::PointerType::getUnqual( llvm::Type::getInt8Ty( ctx ) )
    );

    llvm::GetElementPtrInst *const inc =
        llvm::GetElementPtrInst::Create( intToPtr8, sizeof_T, "inc", block );

    llvm::CastInst *const cast = llvm::CastInst::CreatePointerCast(
        inc, llvm::Type::getInt64Ty( ctx ), "cast", block
    );

    llvm::Constant *const intToPtr64 = llvm::ConstantExpr::getIntToPtr(
        pptrAsInt64, llvm::PointerType::getUnqual( llvm::Type::getInt64Ty( ctx ) )
    );

    llvm::StoreInst *const store = new llvm::StoreInst( cast, intToPtr64, false, block );
    store->setAlignment( 8 );
}

template<typename T>
inline void pointerInc( T **pptr, llvm::BasicBlock *block ) {
    llvm::LLVMContext &ctx = block->getContext();
    llvm::ConstantInt *const sizeof_T =
        llvm::ConstantInt::get( llvm::Type::getInt64Ty( ctx ), sizeof( T ) );
    pointerInc( ptrToValue( pptr, ctx ), sizeof_T, block );
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.  It's the body of (the larger) `pointerInc()` that's wrong.  The code is actually derived from LLVM C++ API code generated by `llc` on an ordinary C++ program that increments a pointer.

When run, the program prints:

```
&p = 140734551679784
--------------------
; ModuleID = 'lt'

define void @func() {
entry:
  %inc = getelementptr i8* inttoptr (i64 140734551679784 to i8*), i64 4
  %cast = ptrtoint i8* %inc to i64
  store i64 %cast, i64* inttoptr (i64 140734551679784 to i64*), align 8
  ret void
}
Segmentation fault: 11 (core dumped)
```

There are two questions:

1. Is this correct?  Can I even do what I want, i.e., share a raw C++ pointer with JIT'd code?
2. Why is it dumping core?

Even if I made the JIT'd function be empty, the code *still* core dumps at the line that calls the function.  The LLVM JIT set-up code looks like all the examples I've seen, so I don't see what's wrong with that either.

A little help?

---

## Update

If I change the deprecated line:

```
void *const func_ptr = exec->getPointerToFunction( func );
```

to the new line:

```
uint64_t const func_ptr = exec->getFunctionAddress( "func" );
```

then `func_ptr` is null.

Comment: I wrote about something similar here: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/calling-back-into-python-from-llvmlite-jited-code -- it's using Python bindings for LLVM, but the main idea is the same -- make the JIT code aware of something in the host program

Comment: I don't think it's similar enough. You seem to be calling a function from JIT'd code. I just want to increment a pointer from the JIT'd code.

Comment: You might ask on some [LLVM-dev](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/mailman/listinfo/llvmdev) mailing list or on some [LLVM IRC channel](http://llvm.org/docs/#irc). You might also use some other technology: [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), `libjit`, `asmjit` etc; and you could list the produced assembler code to understand more of it.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas: precisely. It's a method to bridge from JIT back to host code. Implement a host-side functions that increments the pointer. Call it from JIT. Done. Besides it seems like you're having trouble getting the JIT to work at all, regardless of what it's doing?

Answer (score 2):

After playing around a lot more with `lcc` (and using better C++ code to feed into it), I have it working:

```
llvm::Value* pointerToPointer( void *ptr, llvm::BasicBlock *block ) {
    using namespace llvm;
    LLVMContext &ctx = block->getContext();
    ConstantInt *const ptrAsInt =
        ConstantInt::get( IntegerType::get( ctx, 64 ), (uint64_t)ptr );
    PointerType *const Int8Ptr_type = Type::getInt8PtrTy( ctx );
    PointerType *const Int8PtrPtr_type = PointerType::getUnqual( Int8Ptr_type );
    return new IntToPtrInst( ptrAsInt, Int8PtrPtr_type, "pptr", block );
}

void pointerInc( llvm::Value *pptr, llvm::ConstantInt *sizeof_T,
                llvm::BasicBlock *block ) {
    using namespace llvm;
    LLVMContext &ctx = block->getContext();

    LoadInst *const ptr = new LoadInst( pptr, "ptr", block );
    ptr->setAlignment( sizeof(void*) );

    GetElementPtrInst *const inc =
        GetElementPtrInst::Create( ptr, sizeof_T, "inc", block );

    StoreInst *const store = new StoreInst( inc, pptr, block );
    store->setAlignment(sizeof(void*));
}

template<typename T>
inline void pointerInc( T **pptr, llvm::BasicBlock *block ) {
    using namespace llvm;
    LLVMContext &ctx = block->getContext();
    ConstantInt *const sizeof_T = ConstantInt::get(
        IntegerType::get( ctx, 64 ), (uint64_t)sizeof( T )
    );
    pointerInc( pointerToPointer( pptr, block ), sizeof_T, block );
}
```

However, the program runs successfully only when the JIT'd function is called via:

```
vector<GenericValue> noargs;
exec->runFunction( func, noargs );
```

Using either `getFunctionAddress()` or `getPointerToFunction()` dumps core. I still don't have an answer to that.